# Error: SQLSTATE[HY093] upon insert, but can't find error in code

Tags: php, mysql

Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Let's say we are looking at one row where:

```
$row['ConvLog'] = '12/29/2014 2:44PM - working with the lender to remove the mortgage late so we are able to refinance the client.  - User 1 12/04/2014 2:27PM - file suspended until rapid rescore comes back removing late payment from credit.  - User 2 12/02/2014 2:25PM - Check stubs to Lorena. - User 3';
```

I have triple checked my database column names with the names below and they match up. Why am I receiving this error?

Script:

```
<?php 
$host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.'', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {

            $string = $row['ConvLog'];
     // $column1 = $row[0]; just the ID, don't need to copy
      $column2 = $row[1];
      $column3 = $row[2];
      $column4 = $row[3];

?>

<?php

preg_match_all('/(.*)([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2,4})(.*)/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "<br>";
   /* echo "part 1: " . $val[1] . "<br>";
    echo "part 2: " . $val[2] . "<br>";
    echo "part 3: " . $val[3] . "<br>";
    echo "part 4: " . $val[4] . "<br><br>"; */

// start crazy shit

$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test4 VALUES(:id,:columnA,:columnB,:Processor,:Originator,:FOLDER,:Filename,:LoanAmount,:Rate,:LastName,:FirstName,:Subject Property Address,:City,:County,:CurrentStatus,:CurrentStartDate,:EstCloseDate,:CreditRpt,:Prospect,:PrePacking,:Application,:SenttoProc,:TitleOrdered,:TitleRecvd,:Submitted,:Approved,:RateLocked,:RateLockedStatus,:RateLock,:RateExp,:Suspended,:ReSubmitted,:CleartoClose,:DocsDrawn,:DocsOut,:Docs Recd,$column2:Closed,:Funded,:Recorded,:Denied,:Cancelled,:LOHold,:LoHoldField,:EscrowHold,:EscrowHoldField,:Loan Program,:CC Scenario,:Subject Property State,:Subject Property Zip Code,:Broker Fee,:Broker Pts,:Broker Flat,:Lender Name,:Lender Cpny Name,:Appraisal Rpt,:Late Basic Docs,:Late Miscellaneous,:Late VODs,:Late VOEs,:Late VOLs,:Late VOMs,:Outstanding Docs,:Outstanding Misc,:Outstanding Verifs,:Outstanding Conditions,:Purc,:Escrow Company,:Appraisal Ordered,:ConvLog,:Appraisal Required,:Suspended Reason,:LO Hold Reason,:Escrow Hold Reason,:Appraisal Ordered Status,:AppraisalOrderedField,:Subordination Ordered Status,:SubordinationOrderedField,:PreUnderwriting Status,:PreUnderwritingField
    )');
  $stmt->execute(array(
':id' => '', ':columnA' => $column2, ':columnB' => $column3, ':Processor' => 'test', ':Originator' => 'test', ':FOLDER' => 'test', ':Filename' => 'test', ':LoanAmount' => 'test', ':Rate' => 'test', ':LastName' => 'test', ':FirstName' => 'test', ':Subject Property Address' => 'test', ':City' => 'test', ':County' => 'test', ':CurrentStatus' => 'test', ':CurrentStartDate' => 'test', ':EstCloseDate' => 'test', ':CreditRpt' => 'test', ':Prospect' => 'test', ':PrePacking' => 'test', ':Application' => 'test', ':SenttoProc' => 'test', ':TitleOrdered' => 'test', ':TitleRecvd' => 'test', ':Submitted' => 'test', ':Approved' => 'test', ':RateLocked' => 'test', ':RateLockedStatus' => 'test', ':RateLock' => 'test', ':RateExp' => 'test', ':Suspended' => 'test', ':ReSubmitted' => 'test', ':CleartoClose' => 'test', ':DocsDrawn' => 'test', ':DocsOut' => 'test', ':Docs Recd' => 'test', ':Closed' => 'test', ':Funded' => 'test', ':Recorded' => 'test', ':Denied' => 'test', ':Cancelled' => 'test', ':LOHold' => 'test', ':LoHoldField' => 'test', ':EscrowHold' => 'test', ':EscrowHoldField' => 'test', ':Loan Program' => 'test', ':CC Scenario' => 'test', ':Subject Property State' => 'test', ':Subject Property Zip Code' => 'test', ':Broker Fee' => 'test', ':Broker Pts' => 'test', ':Broker Flat' => 'test', ':Lender Name' => 'test', ':Lender Cpny Name' => 'test', ':Appraisal Rpt' => 'test', ':Late Basic Docs' => 'test', ':Late Miscellaneous' => 'test', ':Late VODs' => 'test', ':Late VOEs' => 'test', ':Late VOLs' => 'test', ':Late VOMs' => 'test', ':Outstanding Docs' => 'test', ':Outstanding Misc' => 'test', ':Outstanding Verifs' => 'test', ':Outstanding Conditions' => 'test', ':Purc' => 'test', ':Escrow Company' => 'test', ':Appraisal Ordered' => 'test', ':ConvLog' => 'test', ':Appraisal Required' => 'test', ':Suspended Reason' => 'test', ':LO Hold Reason' => 'test', ':Escrow Hold Reason' => 'test', ':Appraisal Ordered Status' => 'test', ':AppraisalOrderedField' => 'test', ':Subordination Ordered Status' => 'test', ':SubordinationOrderedField' => 'test', ':PreUnderwriting Status' => 'test', ':PreUnderwritingField' => 'test'
  ));

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

// end crazy shit

}

?>

<?php      
    }   
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Here is an example with only 5 columns, but I still can't get it to work with the backticks. I have tried it with backticks on one, then the other and both. What am I doing wrong?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(:id,`:my number`,:blah,:cool,:notes)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':id' => '', `:my number` => $column2, ':blah' => $column3, ':cool' => $column4, 'notes' => $val[0]
  ));
```

Updated example for 5 columns:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test2 (id, `my number`, blah, cool, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  $stmt->execute(array('', 'test', 'test', 'test','test'));
```

Comment: `:Subject Property Address` <= right there. Wrap any column names in ticks `\`` when spaces are used. That is but one, you have others. Then you have `$column2:Closed` so unsure what you want to do here. This is a debug question. Whoever wants to tackle this and submit an answer; *good luck*. You've quite a bit of work ahead of you.

Comment: *"but can't find error in code"* - It's telling you. Start by that one, then move on to the next error it will give you.

Comment: Wow, great catch. $column2:Closed should just be :Closed, not sure how that var got in there.. I'll update with the back ticks.

Comment: Do you see all the spaces you have in many of your column names? There should not be any or you can rename them with no spaces in your DB, or do as I said earlier and wrap them in tick `\`` - Column names should not contain spaces in them.

Comment: I noticed your edit. Try removing the ticks around `:my number` in the array and use quotes like you did for the others.

Comment: I tried doing that and vice versa, but I still could not get it to work. I will update with what I got to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Yoda do you still need help with this ? I posted an answer few days ago but did not hear from you

Comment: I updated my question with what ended up working for me. Thank you for your answer though and following up.

Answer (score 0):

`:my number` is not a good placeholder name change it to `:mynumber` or `:my_number` just avoid that space.

```
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(:id,:mynumber,:blah,:cool,:notes)
```

then when you bind (quotes not backticks):

```
':mynumber' => $column2.
```

- The only time you need backtics is on the columns or tables not the
  placeholder.
- The rule for placeholder name is alphanumeric and underscore